# jquery script does not execute

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Currently, I am using jquery, php and codeigniter to write a program - However, I've come across a problem.

When I write view file using the codeigniter php framework, I cannot execute the JQuery by using the URL `127.0.0.1/ci/welcome/passdataview/6/7`. If I use `127.0.0.1/ci/welcome/passdataview`, the JQuery script can be executed.

Can anyone tell me how to execute the jquery script with codeigniter parameter in URL?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
alert ("here");
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div><h2>demo 1</h2></div>
<input type="hidden" id="hidden1" value="<?php echo $username;?>">
<input type="hidden" id="hidden2" value="<?php echo $subject;?>">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/ci/js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>`

Comment: `127.0.0.1/ci/welcome/passdataview/6/7` doesn't have any "parameter in URL". Is it meant to be something like `127.0.0.1/ci/welcome/passdataview?username=6&subject=7`?

Answer (score 4):

Might be your jquery file problem, try loading url helper and use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('js/jquery-1.7.1.js');?>"></script>
```

Works no matter how you changed your folder or directory path.